# Performance degradation while updating tables having 10s of millions of records

Tags: postgresql, performance, update, query-performance

I want to update tables ( my be 20-30 ) having 10s of millions of records each.

The problem is that it is taking too much time for the update process and also at that time CPU usage also goes very high. I want to do in such a way that it can not use much CPU while processing the data. If the processing time is increased then it will not be a problem for me but it should use limited CPU resources for processing ( updating ) the table. I am using PostgreSQL as database and server operating system is Linux.

Sample query of mine can be like this

```
UPDATE TEMP 
SET CUSTOMERNAME = 
  ( select customername from user where user.customerid = temp.customerid );
```

Comment: You really need to include the code for the update.  It could be CPU intensive because you are doing some complicated function on every row.

Comment: I am just executing the update query in the table. For example `UPDATE TEMP SET CUSTOMERNAME = ( select customername from user where user.customerid = temp.customerid ) ;`

Comment: Put that into your question, please.  I'm not sure how PG handles subqueries but that could be an issue since it may get executed once per row.  A non-specific answer here will be too general, so you need to give us a scenario to solve.

Comment: Is there an index on `user.customerid` and on `temp.customerid`? Adding an index if there isn't one might help.

Comment: Where should I place index on temp table or user table ?

Comment: how temporary is `TEMP`? you should probably index `USER` (if it isn't already indexed) --- especially with the new information that this is production. Run `EXPLAIN UPDATE TEMP 
SET CUSTOMERNAME = 
  ( select customername from user where user.customerid = temp.customerid );` and `EXPLAIN UPDATE temp
  SET customername = user.customername
  FROM user
  WHERE user.customerid = temp.customerid;` and post the results, please.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The first question is: Why is it important that you not use a lot of CPU time? The query will be bottlenecked on *some* resource; if you could introduce enough additional disk access, the CPU time used per second would go down, but would that really be an improvement?  What resource would you prefer to saturate?  Understanding why you have emphasized this might help guide people to providing an answer that you will find useful.

As suggested in a comment, your query may run faster with a join rather than a correlated subquery.  Something like this:

```
UPDATE temp
  SET customername = user.customername
  FROM user
  WHERE user.customerid = temp.customerid;
```

Another important thing to know is whether you want to update all rows in the table.  Are some of the values already correct?  If so, you will get a big performance boost by not updating the rows that don't need it.  Add `AND temp.customername is distinct from user.customername` to the `WHERE` clause.

If you limit the number of rows updated in each statement, and `VACUUM ANALYZE` after each UPDATE, you will avoid table bloat.  If the point of the desire to minimize CPU time is to avoid a performance impact on concurrent transactions, this would give you the opportunity to introduce a short delay (in the form of a `sleep` or something similar) before you start the next `UPDATE` of a set of rows.

Even better, why are you redundantly storing the information in the temp table rather than joining to it when needed?  (Sometimes there is a good reason; quite often there isn't.)

Comment: Because it is main server and it is live machine if the CPU usage gets higher then its performance will be degraded and it will not be able to do other tasks for which it is made.

Comment: Great answer with many choices. And here I was just going to ask him to `EXPLAIN` between his query and the query which I'd rewritten (and looks like yours) :)

Comment: @BhavikAmbani there is still the unanswered question of why you're storing this data in a table called `TEMP`. Are you preparing to introduce change into the environment and this is your DR strategy? Do you have dev/test/stage environments in which this could be attempted first?

Comment: I have just named as temp but actual name is different

Comment: @BhavikAmbani ok, good to know. so why not, as kgrittn noted, just join to gain the data instead of redundantly storing data?

Comment: @BhavikAmbani: If this is not a temporary table, how do you intend to ensure that the names stay current in the other tables as name changes occur in the source table? If you normalize to 3rd normal form, you won't have problems with that. Don't believe FUD about joins being slow -- normalize first, and look to optimize when you hit an actual problem. There will usually be a better solution than denormalizing. Premature optimization causes a great many problems.

Answer (score 5):

If you follow the very good advice of kgrittn and still have performance issues, you may need to perform the update in batches.  You would still perform set-based updates but limit them to the first 1000 (or whatever number works for you, I've used from 500 to 50,000)records that don't match and then keep looping until all are done.

Answer (score 1):

If there is an index on `TEMP.CUSTOMERNAME` and you are updating a significant part of the `TEMP` table then drop that index before the update and rebuild it after.

Comment: I do not have index on customer name.

Answer (score 1):

PostgreSQL has no way to reduce the amount of CPU time a process can use.  On Linux you can use OS features like the *renice* command to do that.  See [Priorities](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Priorities) for more information and some samples.

Comment: For that will I have to create one another user then assign memory to him ?